# How to doc a variable number of parameters

Tags: php, javascript, phpdoc, jsdoc

How do I doc a variable number of parameters? I am writing an application in PHP and JavaScript. Currently I have (in JavaScript):

```
/**
 * Description
 * @param {String} description
 */
function fn()
{
  // arguments holds all strings.
}
```

So, how do I doc n-number of string params?

Comment: Not sure whether "doctype" is the correct choice of word here.

Comment: Do you mean how to write those parameters in the jsdoc?

Comment: Are you asking for Javascript or PHP? Your code is JS, but you accepted a PHP answer. If its PHP, please change (or remove) the example and also remove the javascript and jsdoc tags. For JS there already is an answer to this in the linked question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729516/correct-way-to-document-open-ended-argument-functions-in-jsdoc).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

E.g. [PhpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/) suggests using an ellipsis

```
/**
 * Example of unlimited parameters.
 * Returns a formatted var_dump for debugging purposes
 * (since the recurrences of $v are not listed in the actual function signature in the code,
 * you may wish to highlight they are "optional" in their description)
 * @param string $s string to display
 * @param mixed $v variable to display with var_dump()
 * @param mixed $v,... unlimited OPTIONAL number of additional variables to display with var_dump()
 */
function fancy_debug($s,$v)
{
```

Comment: Beat me to it. Reference: http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.param.pkg.html

Comment: What about when it's entirely varargs like `function foo() { $args = func_get_args(); ... }` ?