# Correct way to document open-ended argument functions in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

Let's say you have something like the following:

```
var someFunc = function() {
    // do something here with arguments
}
```

How would you correctly document that this function can take any number of arguments in JSDoc? This is my best guess, but I'm not sure it's correct.

```
/**
 * @param {Mixed} [...] Unlimited amount of optional parameters
 */
var someFunc = function() {
    // do something here with arguments
}
```

Related to: [php - How to doc a variable number of parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590428/how-to-doc-a-variable-number-of-parameters)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

The [JSDoc specs](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html#multiple-types-and-repeatable-parameters) and [Google's Closure Compiler](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#variable-parameters-in-param-annotations) do it this way:

```
@param {...number} var_args
```

Where "number" is the type of arguments expected.

The complete usage of this, then, would look like the following:

```
/**
* @param {...*} var_args
*/
function lookMaImVariadic(var_args) {
    // Utilize the `arguments` object here, not `var_args`.
}
```

Note the comment about utilizing `arguments` (or some offset of `arguments`) to access your additional arguments. `var_args` it just used to signal to your IDE that the argument does indeed exist.

[Rest parameters in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) can take the real parameter one step further to encompass provided values (so no more use of `arguments` is necessary):

```
/**
* @param {...*} var_args
*/
function lookMaImES6Variadic(...var_args) {
    // Utilize the `var_args` array here, not `arguments`.
}
```

Comment: This is probably as close to an answer as we can get :)

Comment: Also worth noting, WebStorm's internal JSDoc files (DHTML.js, etc) use this same syntax.  Maybe it's the de-facto standard.

Comment: it's also described quite well here: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html (section 'Allows a parameter to be repeated')

Comment: This answer should be edited to integrate Adrian Holovaty's answer: there *needs* to be an actual variable called `var_args` or whatever you want to call in as the sole parameter. Sad hack.

Comment: With the addition of [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in ES6, this makes a lot more sense. `/** @param {...Function} tasks The tasks. */ function waterfallTasks(...tasks) {` Rest parameters always have a functional presence in the parameters.

Comment: What if my function has single concrete param followed by spread one? I mean `@param {SomeType} x @param {...SomeOtherType} y` confuses Webstorm. He recognises x as `SomeOtherType`. Function signature looks like this: `function foo(x, ...y)`

Comment: The @ param {...*} notation doesn't work with closure compiler, though @ param {...} does. Apparently @ type {...*} works though.

Comment: For me this results in "A rest parameter must be last in a parameter list. ts (1014)" error if the parameter being documented is nested in something like an option block: `param {...*} [options.rest] The rest of my options.`

Answer (score 33):

How to do this is [now described](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#multiple-types-and-repeatable-parameters) in the JSDoc documentation, and it uses an ellipsis like the Closure docs do.

```
@param {...<type>} <argName> <Argument description>
```

You need to supply a type to go after the ellipsis, but you can use a `*` to describe accepting anything, or use the `|` to separate multiple acceptable types.  In the generated documentation JSDoc will describe this argument as *repeatable*, in the same way it describes optional arguments as *optional*.

In my testing there was no need to have an argument in the actual javascript function definition, so your actual code can just have empty parentheses, i.e. `function whatever() { ... }`.

Single type:

```
@param {...number} terms Terms to multiply together
```

Any type (in the example below, the square brackets mean `items` will get tagged as both optional and repeatable):

```
@param {...*} [items] - zero or more items to log.
```

Multiple types need parentheses around the type list, with the ellipsis before the opening paren:

```
@param {...(Person|string)} attendees - Meeting attendees, listed as either 
                                        String names or {@link Person} objects
```

Comment: And what about object used as key-value pairs ?. Currently I use: `@param {{...(key: value)}} [config] - specific configs for this transfer` but was wondering if this is correct ?

Comment: @Max I can't tell from the docs if that's the official right way to do it, but it looks like it should work as expected.  So if it generates output you are okay with, I'd use it :)

Answer (score 11):

From the [JSDoc users group](http://groups.google.com/group/jsdoc-users/browse_thread/thread/3d742a9ebc638f2/f2ad627e40ccaf75&usg=AFQjCNEa9wVQdH8E2J5hUvVcBLt-aRtFwA):

> There isn't any official way, but one possible solution is this:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @param [...] Zero or more child nodes. If zero then ... otherwise ....
>  */
> ```
>
> The square brackets indicate an optional parameter, and the ... would  (to me) indicate "some arbitrary number."
>
> Another possibility is this...
>
> ```
> /**
>  * @param [arguments] The child nodes.
>  */
> ```
>
> Either way should communicate what you mean.

It's a bit dated, though (2007), but I'm not aware of anything more current.

If you need to document the param type as 'mixed', use `{*}`, as in `@param {*} [arguments]`.

Comment: I don't mind having my answer downvoted, but I do expect a comment explaining why you did it (whoever you are). If you think it is wrong, let me - and all of us - know why.

Comment: My IDE of choice (WebStorm 8.0.1) supports syntax #2 `@param [arguments]` (or `@param {*} [arguments]` for that matter) as well as the syntax established by Google Closure compiler (mentioned in another answer). `@param [...]` is not supported.

Comment: @mistaecko but only with named parameters correct? That's what I'm not using, so this isn't a acceptable answer for me...

Answer (score 11):

I futzed with this for quite some time. Here's how to do it with Google Closure Compiler:

```
/**
* @param {...*} var_args
*/
function my_function(var_args) {
    // code that accesses the magic 'arguments' variable...
}
```

The key is to give your function a `var_args` parameter (or whatever you call it in your `@param` statement) even though the function doesn't actually use that parameter.