# how to doc variadic param in jsdoc?

Tags: variadic, param, jsdoc

how to doc variadic  param in jsdoc?
and is there a way to doc param of type like "Array of string" ?

Comment: It looks like @aztack means he wants to document a variadic function that takes any number of arrays. The arrays consist of strings. In this case, the correct answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/4841722/1170723

Comment: @param {...array.<string>} arrs Any number of string array args